# Odoo 13: Module Contacts: How can I store ids (e.g. [4, 8, 9]) as a new field for each contact

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have got a few ids (e.g. [4, 8, 9]) and I would like to store them as a new field in module Contacts (python code). The number of ids may vary for each contact. Moreover, I would like to use this new field in filter. What type of field do I need?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use One2Many field to store such data, but you need to know what model your `id`s is. Something like this:

```
children_ids = fields.One2many('child.model', 'parent_id')
```

Then in the child model, you should have a Many2One field named `parent_id` (you can change the field name) so it can to refer back to its parent. Something like this:

```
parent_id = fields.Many2one('parent.model')
```

For filter feature, [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/adding-all-fields-of-one2many-field-in-search-advance-filters-add-custom-filters-section-in-odoo-176805) may guide you on how to do it. Basically, you can add the field into the search. Something like this:

```
<field name="children_ids" string="Children IDs" filter_domain="[('children_ids.some_field','ilike', self)]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this new field (childer_ids) automatically saved in DB? How can I use this field in the filter?

Comment: @Erik I have edited the answer to include the information needed for the filter ability and the link also mentions that the One2Many fields do not store in the DB as is, but it will have its own table.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for your answer. I wish I could give you the vote but my reputation score is below 15. As soon as I get above it I will give you the vote. Thank you once again... :)